# $(\partial_{xx}+\partial_{t})g=f$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am relatively familiar with the heat equation and using Schauder estimates when studying the regularity of the solution, i.e. for some given $g$ in some function space finding an $f$ which solves
$$(\partial_{xx}-\partial_{t})f=g$$
$$f(0)=f_0.$$
This equation can be solved by convolving with the fundamental solution which is a gaussian kernel, i.e. one can use semi-group theory.

I was wandering how things change if the minus in the equation is replaced by a plus, i.e. if we study
$$(\partial_{xx}+\partial_{t})f=g$$
$$f(0)=f_0.$$
Can we still derive Schauder-like estimates? Or is the equation fundamentally different?

Comment: It is possible, but the backwards heat equation is not always well posed. See [here, especially the answer with the ArXiv links](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952978/the-backwards-heat-equation-is-not-well-posed)